# Calculate the F1 score of precision and recall in R

Tags: r, precision-recall, f-statistic

Alright so I want to calculate the F1 score for four pair of values for Precision P and Recall R. These pairs are:

```
Precision = (54.54, 60.0, 91.3, 95.23)
Recall = (0.02, 2.10, 0.18, 5.3)
```

The above is the percentage of these values

```
Precision1 = ( 0.5454 0.6000 0.9130 0.9523)
Recall1 = ( 0.0002 0.0210 0.0018 0.0530)
```

The following formula calculates the F1 score

[image]

In other words

```
Fscore = (2*Precision*Recall) / sum(Precision, Recall)
```

For both pairs of precision and recall values the results are:

```
Fscore = (0.03998534  4.05797101  0.35929165 10.04116184) #using the Precision/Recall
Fscore1 = (7.067742e-05 8.164059e-03 1.064827e-03 3.270282e-02) #Precision1/Recall1
```

However I am not sure about those numbers. Which of the two am I supposed to use? Am I missing something? I though the Fscore values range from 1 to 0. Do I have to normalize any of these numbers?

Comment: Is the range of Fscore from 0 to 1 or is it only when the values are normalized like that?

Comment: With R you might want to use the `ROCR` library that computes any desired indicator for binary classif. I've set up [an app](https://agenis.shinyapps.io/tutorial-classifier/) to play with a classifier and see how these metrics change here.

Answer (score 3):

F1Score ranges from 0-1, you're right.

Keep in mind how precision and recall is calculated

```
precision = TP / (TP + FP)
recall = TP / (TP + FN)
```

with `TP` = True positives, `FP` = False positives and `FN` = false negatives. Therefore,  precision is the fraction of retrieved instances that are relevant, while recall is the fraction of relevant instances that are retrieved (like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) puts it).

Given that definition, precision and recall are both percentual values (range from 0%-100% = 0-1). Therefore you should go with your `XXX1` versions, because your `Precsion` (without the 1) does not satisfy that criteria. But please note, that your recall is with values lower than 0,02 **extremly** low.

Answer (score 3):

You Need to take the numbers between 0 and 1 and not the percent values. Please check the syntax, however, as I think, there is an error hidden. Precision and Recall are two vectors. You are computing `sum(Precision, Recall)` where I think you should compute `Precision + Recall`. Note, that these are not the same in R. The `sum` function will add all the values in both vectors to one large number, whilst the `+` will add element wise:

```
> a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
> b <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
> sum(a,b)
[1] 8
> a+b
[1] 2 2 2 2
```

The more Precision/Recall pairs you have, the smaller the results of your function (using `sum`) will get, as they all have a growing denominator.

To come back to your example data, that would be:

```
Precision1 <- c(0.5454, 0.6000, 0.9130, 0.9523)
Recall1 <- c(0.0002, 0.0210, 0.0018, 0.0530)
Fscore_rev <- 2 * Precision1 * Recall1 / (Precision1 + Recall1)
```

and yield

```
> round(Fscore_rev, 4)
[1] 0.0004 0.0406 0.0036 0.1004
```

Answer (score 2):

By definition, Precision and Recall should range form 0 to 1.
Use the decimal representation of Precision and Recall:

```
Precision <- c( 0.5454 0.6000 0.9130 0.9523 )
Recall <- c( 0.0002 0.0210 0.0018 0.0530 )
numerator <- 2*Precision*Recall
print(numerator)
[1] 0.00021816 0.02520000 0.00328680 0.10094380

denominator <- (Precision + Recall)
print(denominator)
[1] 0.5456 0.6210 0.9148 1.0053

Fscore <- numerator/denominator
```

The answer is:

```
print( Fscore)
[1] 0.0003998534 0.0405797101 0.0035929165 0.1004116184
```